# Django, how do it in template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I need display like this :

```
{% if user_rate %}
    <h2><a href="/games/{{game.id}}/{{game.slug}}/add_rate/edit/{{rate.id}}/">Edit rate</a></h2>
{% else %}
 <h2><a href="/games/{{game.id}}/{{game.slug}}/add_rate">Add rate</a></h2>
{% endif %}
```

but when I used ( If I rate first game)
`user_rate = Rate.objects.filter(user=request.user)`
It display me "Edit" in the game without rate. `objects.get()` give me :
"get() returned more than one Rate -- it returned 2!"

and I want to display

```
 {% for x in user_rate %}
 Your rate : {{x.rate}}
 {% endfor %}
```

but this also display user's rate from all games. I have the same structure in comments and it's works, I see only my comments from this game, but I don't know why it doesn't work with rate of the game...

```
class Rate(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Games)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    rate = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1),
                                   MaxValueValidator(10)])

    class Meta:
    unique_together = ['game', 'user']
```

views.py

```
def game(request, game_id, slug):
    game = Games.objects.get(id = game_id)
    genre = game.genres.all()
    platform = game.platforms.all()
    quantity = Games.objects.all().count()
    user = User.objects.all().count()
    number_of_rates = Rate.objects.filter(game_id = game_id).count()
    rate_average = Rate.objects.filter(game_id = game_id).aggregate(Avg("rate")).values()[0]



    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user_rate = Rate.objects.filter(user=request.user)


        ctx = {'game' : game, 'genre' : genre, 'platform' : platform, 'quantity' :quantity, \
        'user' : user, 'rate_average' : rate_average, 'user_rate': user_rate, \
       'number_of_rates' : number_of_rates}
        return render(request, 'game.html', ctx)

    else:
        ctx = {'game' : game, 'genre' : genre, 'platform' : platform, 'quantity' :quantity, \
        'user' : user, 'rate_average' : rate_average, 'number_of_rates' : number_of_rates}
        return render(request, 'game.html', ctx)
```

Comment: u need to have a flag that says if a user has rated or not.

Comment: how to make this flag?

Comment: send the flag from the view

Comment: Mayble example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Something along the lines of this.
rate = Rate.objects.get(user=request.user)
context = {...., "user": request.user, "rate": rate}
return render(request, 'template.html', context=context)
```

In your template:

```
 {% if rate %}
    <h2><a href="/games/{{game.id}}/{{game.slug}}/add_rate/edit/{{rate.id}}/">Edit rate</a></h2>
{% else %}
     <h2><a href="/games/{{game.id}}/{{game.slug}}/add_rate">Add rate</a></h2>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: should be Rate.objects.filter, not get, but now it work. Thank you very much.

Comment: I cannot conclude that based off of your question. Also, second thing. Filter returns a LIST, get returns a single item or an error, so for your use case it might be best to use .get() and not filter. If this answer is the correct answer, please accept it as such. @abcdefghijklmn8

Comment: If I give "get" I get error about Rate matching query.

Comment: You're right. Get is best to use... Maybe you will read this. You know, how do this with get, If I have a error? If I have 1 rate I have Rate query error, If I have two rate, I have get() returned more than one Rate -- it returned 2!
. Please help @Borko Kovacev

Comment: Could you update your question to show the exact Rate query error and your models? Does your modeling allow for multiple rates per game from a single user?  @abcdefghijklmn8

Comment: queston updated, one user can rate one game, if he tried add the same rate again he get 'unique_together' error.
But now If user rate game1, in game2, game3 etc. he see only "Edit".
@Borko Kovacev

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. I'm stupid.
Maybe someone someday will use it.

So I needed just

```
Rate.objects.filter(user = request.user, game_id = game_id)
```

It was easy, and I had a lot of problem with that.